# install i386-elf-gcc on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, cross-compiling, xv6

I'm building cross-compilation toolchain for Ubuntu following [this link](https://github.com/remzi-arpacidusseau/ostep-projects/blob/master/INSTALL-xv6.md) (originally for MacOS).

After installing a few libraries (`qemu-system-x86`, `build-essential`, `gcc-multilib`), I managed to use `i386-elf-gcc`. Then after closing previous shell, I lose access to `i386-elf-gcc`:

> make: i386-elf-gcc: Command not found

I guess some PATH become invalid for operations I don't remember.

Now how do I bring back `i386-elf-gcc` for Ubuntu?

Also, `$ objdump -i` get me `elf32-i386` at 3rd line, does it mean that `i386-elf-gcc` is installed already?

Comment: You can try `find / -name "i386-elf-gcc" 2> /dev/null` to locate it. Or maybe `find / -executable -name "*gcc*" 2> /dev/null` if you're not sure of the name